# Regex to delete all empty lines whatsoever?

Tags: visual-studio-code, lines

In Windows 10 I use a text editor (I'd like not to point out a particular one but I usually use Visual Studio Code AKA "VSCODE").

I need a way to delete all blank lines whatsoever only with regex after I matched them with this code:

```
^\s*$
```

After I match the lines themselves, how is it possible to delete the lines?

AFAIK, regex only edit lines, not deleting lines or adding lines.

I desire a way to delete all matched (empty).

Hitting "Enter" or "Delete" in the empty "replace" box doesn't delete lines:

[image]

Comment: Probably, you need `^\s*$[\n\r]*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close.  You were missing the new line character in your regex.  This worked for me:

```
^\s*$\n
```

Without the newline character, you are matching the blank line itself which you then replace with nothing but you've left the newline character so it still leaves an empty line in place.

Comment: But how did you deleted the empty lines after matching them? Hitting enter after matching the empty lines and their newline characters with `^\s*$\n` didn't actually deleted the lines, sadly (and thanks!).

Comment: Since you are doing a Find and Replace, just leave the Replace field blank.  It then replaces what the regex matches with nothing.  You just have to hit the Replace next or Replace all buttons next to the Replace field.